# control the width of images on the content that comes from a different host

Tags: javascript, css, same-origin-policy, fluid-layout

I want to control the width of images on the content that comes from a different host. This content is displayed inside an iframe. I do not have control over this remote content.

According my tests seems that try to change the width of images (with CSS and javascript) works if the content of iframe comes from the same host, but does not work if comes from a different host. seems that this is limited by Same Origin Policy "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy" (is this correct? or I am wrong?), and seems that the only way will be pull the remote content and do a preprocess (server side) to modify that content (change the width of images) and then display that content, but I do not want to take this way if is possible to do with only CSS or/and javascript. Somebody can give me some guidance about do this with only CSS and/or javascript over the content located in the iframe? (remember that the content comes from a different host).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in your analysis.

If you want to change those images you need

- either the collaboration of the server ([using headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control))
- or a server side kind of proxy to let the browser think there is only one origin

As it's a security system (for the user), there is of course no known workaround on modern browsers.

You can't do it using only a client side cross browser solution.